# Does there exist an upper triangular set of gens of $ k[[X]] $ for a unipotent formal group acting on $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[[X]]) $?

Tags: formal-groups, formal-schemes

For this post I define a formal group to be a group object in the category of formal schemes.

Let $ G $ be a linear algebraic group with affine coordinate ring $ k[G] $.  If $ \mathfrak{m}_{e} $ is the maximal ideal of the identity, then we may endow $ \varprojlim_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} k[G]/\mathfrak{m}_{e}^{i} $ with the structure of a Hopf algebra via the original morphisms $ \mu_{G}^{\sharp},\epsilon_{G}^{\sharp} $ and $ s_{G}^{\sharp} $.  With this structure on $ \varprojlim_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} k[G]/\mathfrak{m}_{e}^{i} $, we may endow the affine, formal scheme $ \operatorname{Spf}_{e}(k[G]) $ with the structure of a formal group.  Call this formal group $ \widehat{G} $ and its affine coordinate ring $ \widehat{k[G]} $.

It is well known that if $ G $ is a unipotent, linear algebraic group and $ \beta: G \to \operatorname{GL}(\mathbf{V}) $ is an $ n $-dimensional, linear representation, then there is an upper triangular basis $ \{x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\} $ of $ \mathbf{V}^{\ast} $, i.e., $ \beta^{\sharp}(x_{i}) \in k[x_{1},\dots,x_{i}] \otimes_{k} k[G] $ for all $ 1 \le i \le n $.

If $ G $ is a unipotent, linear algebraic group, and $ \widehat{G} $ acts on $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[[Y]]) $ via an action $ \beta $, then is there a set of generators $ \{x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\} $ of $ k[[Y]] $ such that $ \beta^{\sharp}(x_{i}) \in k[[x_{1},\dots,x_{i}]] \otimes_{k} \widehat{k[G]} $ for $ 1 \le i \le n $?

If the action $ \beta $ is obtained from an action $ \gamma $ of $ G $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} $, then the answer is yes, but not all actions of $ \widehat{G} $ on $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[[Y]]) $ are obtained from actions of $ G $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} $.

For example, let the characteristic of $ k $ equal zero, let $ G $ equal $ \mathbb{G}_{a} \cong \operatorname{Spec}(k[t]) $ and let $ \delta \in T_{k[Y]/k} $ be a derivation which is not locally nilpotent.  The ring homomorphism which sends $ y_{i} $ to $ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\delta^{j}(y_{i})t^{j}\right)/j! $ is a co-action of $ \widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}} $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} $ which is not obtained from an action of $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} $. From this we obtain an action of $ \widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}} $ on $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[[Y]]) $.  This action is not obtained from an action of $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} $, but there may be a set $ x_{1},\dots,x_{n} \in k[[Y]] $ such that $ k[[X]] \cong k[[Y]] $ and $ \beta^{\sharp}(x_{i}) \in k[[x_{1},\dots,x_{i}]] \otimes k[[t]] $.